# Guidance requested for vector dot product question.

Tags: vectors

Helping my child out with their year 11 exam preparation, specifically vectors and dot products, I *think* I may have figured out the answer but I'd like to get some confirmation or, more likely, a short sharp shock of education :-)

Keep in mind it's some thirty-plus years since I've had to tackle this stuff. The question is phrased thus:

> If vector ***a*** is perpendicular to vector ***b-a***, which of the following are *necessarily* true?
>   1) ***a***.(***b-a***) = 0
>   2) ***a***.***b*** = ***a***.***a***
>   3) ***a*** = ***b***
>   4) ***a***.***b*** = |***a***|<sup>2</sup>

The ones they stated as necessarily true were all but ***3***.

So here is my reasoning. Consider the vectors as follows. If ***b-a*** is perpendicular, then the ***b*** vector must be like this (although the triangle could of course be oriented in other ways):

```
      /|
     / |
    /  |
 b /   | b-a
  /    |
 /     |
/______|
   a
```

Now, obviously, item ***1*** is true because the dot product is `|a||b-a|cosθ`, where `θ = 90` hence `cosθ = 0`.

In terms of the other three statements, I used Pythagoras on the *magnitudes* to work out:

$${b^2} = {a^2} + {(b-a)^2}$$
$${b^2} = {a^2} + {b^2 -2ab + a^2}$$
$${b^2} = {2a^2} + {b^2 -2ab}$$
$${2a^2} = {2ab}$$
$${a} = {b}$$

So it appears the magnitude of ***a*** and ***b*** is the same. That would, of course, mean the triangle is not so much a triangle as two congruent lines. This would explain why items ***2*** and ***4*** were true - ***b-a*** becomes a zero-length vector which I suppose could be considered perpendicular to ***a***.

But the only reason why I can think that item ***3*** could be *false* is if that zero-length vector may corrupt things. The other three statements deal with magnitudes only but it may be that that a zero-length *vector* may be rewritten as zero units north or zero units west, and they *may* be considered different.

Other than that, I'm not sure why item ***3*** would not be true as well. Of course, it's quite possible that I've made some mistake in the reasoning above, in which case I'd appreciate some guidance so I can once again become a hero to my son :-)

Comment: Actually, now that I've asked this, I think I realised that treating the `b-a` *vector* as having a magnitude of `|b|-|a|` was wrong - I think that stuffed things up. Still, I'll leave the question here so someone can point out the issue and hopefully let me know the *correct* way to solve it.

Comment: For part $3$:  Consider an example.  In $\mathbb R^2$, the vector $\vec a=(1,0)$ is orthogonal to $\vec v=(0,3)$, say.  Now, to get that in the right form we need $\vec b$ with $\vec v=\vec b-\vec a\implies \vec b=\vec v+\vec a=(1,3)$.  We note that $\vec a\neq \vec b$ in this case.

Comment: The question asks '*necessarily true*', right? If $a = 0$, then is the condition *necessarily* true? I hope that answers your question!

Comment: @Firefox1921, it was the `b-a` vector that was zero length, not the `a`. My (almost certainly faulty) reasoning with Pythagoras indicated that this was *required* to be the case.

Comment: I see that now @paxdiablo. I stand corrected :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what your son is supposed to know about the dot product... which is critical for the answer.

However if he knows that dot product is distributive vs. addition then $$a \cdot (b-a) = a \cdot b - a \cdot a=0.$$

Therefore 2. is clear and 4. also as $a \cdot a = \vert a \vert^2$.

Comment: He says he didn't know it was distributive over addition but, given he's a teenager, it probably just fell out of his head on the way home one day :-) This certainly makes things a hell of a lot easier than my (mis-)method. Thanks heaps.

Comment: I'm French and we'll try to remember the expression *just fell out of his head on the way home one day* that I like!

Answer (score 2):

Your figure is an example of how $a\cdot(b - a)$ could be true.
Note that $b$ is a different vector from $a$ in that figure,
so it is an example where $a = b$ is false.

For the rest, in general, if vectors $x$ and $y$ are perpendicular the
$x \cdot y = 0.$
This is often used as part of the *definition* of what it means for vectors to be perpendicular.

But $a\cdot (b - a) = a\cdot b - a \cdot a$ (distribution of dot product over addition), so $a\cdot (b - a) = 0$ implies
$a\cdot b - a \cdot a = 0$,
which implies $a\cdot b = a \cdot a.$
Moreover, in general for any vector $a,$ we always have $|a|^2 = a\cdot a.$

Comment: Thanks, David. I knew about the dot product being zero for perpendicular vectors, I'd just forgotten *long* ago about distribution. Appreciate the help.